# Is the API gateway stage level throttling limit shared between the methods or independent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, throttling

is the AWS Rest API Gateway Stage-level throttling limit shared between the methods or independent ?

Assume we have 5 methods in API Gateway, and stage level throttling rate is set to 10tps. Will all the 5 methods share the same 10tps quota, or each one will get their independent quota ? In other words, will overloading one method impact other methods.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html#apigateway-how-throttling-limits-are-applied) says that '*Per-API, per-stage throttling limits are applied at the API method level for a stage. You can configure the same settings for all methods, or configure different throttle settings for each method.*'

As per my understanding, each method should get independent quota. I also did few load tests to validate the same.

But can someone please confirm ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, as explained in the documentation that you quoted. Each method will have its own, independent quota. The general idea is that you can set a throttling for each method of a stage in one place. For example, you have 5 methods and 2 stages. You want each method in dev stage to have a throttling limit of 10 and in prod stage to have a throttling limit of 100. This way, you set a throttling on a stage level and don't have to do it for each method individually (but you can override it for specific method if needed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my view, the related documentation should be made a bit more concise;)